# Exception Access violation when refactoring code - original works but separate files don't

Tags: python, error

I've written a script for a pbd simulation of a chain. The first vertex is pinned to the origin. The others are just vertices extruded in a line

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import time

mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object

# Initialise timestep (seconds), vertex weight (kg), gravity
timestep = 0.5
weight = 0.05
gravity = np.array([0,0,-9.8])

# Ensure it's a mesh and convert to numpy arrays
if mesh_object and mesh_object.type == 'MESH':
    mesh = mesh_object.data
    
    # Extract vertex coordinates as NumPy array
    length = len(mesh.vertices)
    positions = np.empty(length*3, dtype=np.float64)
    mesh.vertices.foreach_get('co', positions)
    positions.shape = (length, 3)
    
    # Extract edges as NumPy array
    edgelength = len(mesh.edges)
    edges = np.empty(edgelength*2, dtype=np.uint8)
    mesh.edges.foreach_get('vertices', edges)
    edges.shape = (edgelength, 2)

    # get edge lengths
    edgelengthsstart = np.empty(edgelength, dtype = np.float64)
    edgevectors = positions[edges[:,1]] - positions[edges[:,0]]
    edgelengthsstart = np.linalg.norm(edgevectors, axis= 1)

    #initialise arrays for distance constraint
    edgevertexdeltas = np.empty((edgelength, 2), dtype = np.float64)
    edgelengthsnew = np.empty(edgelength, dtype = np.float64)
    constraintpositions = np.zeros_like(positions)
else:
    print("Please select a valid mesh object.")


#initialise velocities
velocities = np.zeros_like(positions)
invweights = np.full(len(positions), 1/weight)
invweights[0]=0
invweightratios = np.zeros_like(edges, dtype= np.float64)
invweightratios[:,0]= invweights[edges[:,0]]/(invweights[edges[:,0]]+ invweights[edges[:,1]])
invweightratios[:,1]= invweights[edges[:,1]]/(invweights[edges[:,0]]+ invweights[edges[:,1]])
#print(invweightratios)
#print(velocities)

def update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity, invweightratios):

    #Update velocities and positions
    newpositions=np.copy(positions)
    velocities+= timestep*weight*gravity
    newpositions += timestep*velocities

    # calculate constraints

    for i in range (0,128):
        #v1, v2 = 
        newpositions[0] = [0,0,0]
        edgevectorsnew = newpositions[edges[:,1]] - newpositions[edges[:,0]]
        edgelengthsnew = np.linalg.norm(edgevectorsnew, axis= 1)
        edgedifferences = edgelengthsnew - edgelengthsstart
        edgeratios = edgedifferences/edgelengthsnew
        #print(edgeratios)
        edgevertexdeltasweighted = edgevectorsnew * edgeratios[:, np.newaxis]

        #Update constraint positions
        constraintpositions = np.copy(newpositions)
        constraintpositions[edges[:,1]] -= invweightratios[:,1,np.newaxis]*edgevertexdeltasweighted
        constraintpositions[edges[:,0]] += invweightratios[:,0, np.newaxis]*edgevertexdeltasweighted
        newpositions = np.copy(constraintpositions)
        


    #update velocity and positions
    velocities = (1/timestep)*(newpositions-positions)
    positions = np.copy(newpositions)
    #print(positions)

    # Put it back into mesh
    vertexpositions = np.copy(positions)
    vertexpositions.shape = length*3
    mesh.vertices.foreach_set("co", vertexpositions)
    mesh.update()


    return velocities, positions

for i in range(0,32):   
    velocities, positions = update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity, invweightratios)
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Works fine, however refactoring the code to store the mesh data as a numpy array into another file

```
import numpy as np

#mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object

def meshToNumpy(mesh_object):
    if mesh_object and mesh_object.type == 'MESH':
        mesh = mesh_object.data
        
        # Extract vertex coordinates as NumPy array
        length = len(mesh.vertices)
        positions = np.empty(length*3, dtype=np.float64)
        mesh.vertices.foreach_get('co', positions)
        positions.shape = (length, 3)
        
        # Extract edges as NumPy array
        edgelength = len(mesh.edges)
        edges = np.empty(edgelength*2, dtype=np.uint8)
        mesh.edges.foreach_get('vertices', edges)
        edges.shape = (edgelength, 2)

    else:
        print("Please select a valid mesh object.")

    #print(mesh, positions, length, edges, edgelength)
    return positions, edges, edgelength, length, mesh
```

and

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import time
import blendergetset

mesh_object = bpy.context.active_object

# Initialise timestep (seconds), vertex weight (kg), gravity
timestep = 0.5
weight = 0.05
gravity = np.array([0,0,-9.8])

positions, edges, edgelength, length, mesh = blendergetset.meshToNumpy(mesh_object)

# get edge lengths
edgelengthsstart = np.empty(edgelength, dtype = np.float64)
edgevectors = positions[edges[:,1]] - positions[edges[:,0]]
edgelengthsstart = np.linalg.norm(edgevectors, axis= 1)

#initialise arrays for distance constraint
edgevertexdeltas = np.empty((edgelength, 2), dtype = np.float64)
edgelengthsnew = np.empty(edgelength, dtype = np.float64)
constraintpositions = np.zeros_like(positions)


#initialise velocities
velocities = np.zeros_like(positions)
invweights = np.full(len(positions), 1/weight)
invweights[0]=0
invweightratios = np.zeros_like(edges, dtype= np.float64)
invweightratios[:,0]= invweights[edges[:,0]]/(invweights[edges[:,0]]+ invweights[edges[:,1]])
invweightratios[:,1]= invweights[edges[:,1]]/(invweights[edges[:,0]]+ invweights[edges[:,1]])

def update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity, invweightratios):

    #Update velocities and positions
    newpositions=np.copy(positions)
    velocities+= timestep*weight*gravity
    newpositions += timestep*velocities

    # calculate constraints

    for i in range (0,128):
        #v1, v2 = 
        newpositions[0] = [0,0,0]
        edgevectorsnew = newpositions[edges[:,1]] - newpositions[edges[:,0]]
        edgelengthsnew = np.linalg.norm(edgevectorsnew, axis= 1)
        edgedifferences = edgelengthsnew - edgelengthsstart
        edgeratios = edgedifferences/edgelengthsnew
        #print(edgeratios)
        edgevertexdeltasweighted = edgevectorsnew * edgeratios[:, np.newaxis]

        #Update constraint positions
        constraintpositions = np.copy(newpositions)
        constraintpositions[edges[:,1]] -= invweightratios[:,1,np.newaxis]*edgevertexdeltasweighted
        constraintpositions[edges[:,0]] += invweightratios[:,0, np.newaxis]*edgevertexdeltasweighted
        newpositions = np.copy(constraintpositions)
        


    #update velocity and positions
    velocities = (1/timestep)*(newpositions-positions)
    positions = np.copy(newpositions)
    #print(positions)

    # Put it back into mesh
    vertexpositions = np.copy(positions)
    vertexpositions.shape = length*3
    mesh.vertices.foreach_set("co", vertexpositions)
    mesh.update()


    return velocities, positions

for i in range(0,32):   
    velocities, positions = update(velocities, positions, timestep, weight, gravity, invweightratios)
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Gives me an error exception access violation. What is going on here? it sometimes works but randomly crashes at different times.